# How to diagnose what webcam driver I need?

Tags: drivers, webcam

I have a webcam but I don't know what company/model it is (it doesn't have it written on it)

How can I find out/ find drivers for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the device manager, right click on the webcam and select properties.

There you will find the details tab, click it. Once there, you will see a drop down menu. Click it and select hardware Id. Google the id it shows.

Comment: I don't see it in the control panel :(

Comment: you can find the device manager by right click my computer clicking manage and then device manager on windows 7. On XP its right click My computer -> properties -> advanced tab -> hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can see detail information of your hardware (not only, there are a lot of usable features) using [Everest](http://www.lavalys.com/support/downloads).

Comment: Thanks, yet when looking at the USB list in it - it shows it as unknown.  Any other ideas?